# How to safely use http_proxy variable in linux

Tags: linux, proxy

I got complicated about `http_proxy` on our linux server.
The thing is that we use to go through our proxy, which is preferenced on ldap,
so I must use my machine's login and password in `http_proxy` to be able to download something from the ssh client. I can edit `bash_profile` with that, I can use alias for curl like `curlp` where I could set proxy login and proxy password.

But my password is opened for all my colleagues anyways.

Comment: but its should be inside your homedir so how could others can see?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this one:

Create an encrypted password of your password:

```
openssl enc -aes-256-cbc -in mypassword.txt -out mypassword.bin
```

**Notes:** After running above command remove `mypassword.txt` file which is pain password

Run following command using your `mypassword.bin` secret password:

```
alias myproxy='PASSWORD=`openssl aes-256-cbc -d -in mypassword.bin`; PROXY="http://$USER:$PASSWORD@proxy:$PORT"; export http_proxy=$PROXY; export https_proxy=$PROXY; export ftp_proxy=$PROXY'
```

Comment: I think if we do what you say, and check for the environment variables like so:

`env | grep -i http`

we would still be able to see the password.